# Can a Frum Jew go on a sponsored mixed trip if he can not afford to go to Eretz Yisroel?

Tags: halacha, eretz-yisrael, travel

Is a frum Charedi Jew allowed to go on a [Birthright](https://www.birthrightisrael.com/) trip to Eretz Yisroel? Are there any *gedolim* that say it's *asur*?

I would assume that the following things would be an issue:

- Tznius
- Mixed seating and activities
- Mixed davening
- Not a "pro-frum" movement

Comment: AvorohomKanievsky, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here! Could you please [edit] in some more information about what aspects of Birthright trips may be at issue, Halachically?

Comment: I recall hearing that in recent years they have created more 'Chareidi' tracks of Birthright. That might be worth looking into.

Comment: There are Frum birthright trips you can go on. I have a friend who was a madrich for 30 yeshiva guys who went onba trip. Even had good hashgacha on the food

Comment: @ClintEastwood I allowed myself to roll back because I am not sure what a drummer has to do with the question

Comment: @mbloch he most likely meant "frummer"

Comment: @robev you are right, makes sense now, although now I do think it conflicts with the original intent

Answer (score 4):

Birthright is the general label for a 10-day all-expense paid first trip to Israel. Within that umbrella, different providers organize the actual trips. Some of these providers offer options geared to orthodox/frum/glatt kosher/single-sex participants, for instance

- [Ezra World](https://www.birthrightisrael.com/organizer/market/2?tab=tab_trips) (a youth movement) offers men-only/women-only/couple glatt kosher tours
- [Israel Free Spirit](https://www.israelfreespirit.com/trip/sg/) offers a men-only observant program with extra time in Jerusalem and Tzfat and chareidi hechserim

See the broader list [here](https://www.birthrightisrael.com/market?interest=48).

Of course, [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734) and to discuss whether it would be appropriate for a specific individual.